# Bundler: How do I get the groups from the current Gemfile at runtime?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I already have this...

`File.read(Bundler.default_gemfile).scan(/group :(\w+)/).flatten`

with an example output of

`["production", "test", "development"]`

...but Im hoping there is a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit cleaner:

```
> Bundler.definition.groups
# => [:default, :development, :test]
```

Of course this returns the `:default` group, which you may wish to get rid of.

Comment: How to get current effective groups? Without the excludes for example.